# How to extract Integers from a String that are next to Non-Integers?

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

I am doing a fairly simple Poker kata that compares two hands and outputs a winner.

I have a String --> "2D, 3D, 6H, 10D, KS". For my solution I need the Numbers and Suites in different lists. I tried tackling it using substrings;

```
// Seperate card number and suite
int num = Integer.parseInt(mainHand.substring(0, 1));
String suite = mainHand.substring(1,2);
mainHand = mainHand.substring(4);
```

The problem is however when the String contains a 10 it obviously stops working as "10".length()>1.

Therefore I tried

```
int num = scanner.nextInt();
```

But all I get is an InputMismatchException, i'm assuming its due to the non-int next to it.

Am I using Scanner wrong? And is there a better way to split these two into lists?

Comment: So where "`K`" (from the last element) would go?

Comment: Suite is always 1 character, right? So start from the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first split the String:

```
 String[] parts = str.split(",\\s*")
```

then for each part you can use relative to its end substrings (as it seems suite is just one character):

```
 int splitIdx = part.length - 1;
 int num = Integer.parseInt(part.substring(0, splitIdx));
 String suite = mainHand.substring(splitIdx);
```